# Tunnelblick/Viscosity random connection issues even when not connected to VPN

Tags: network, vpn

I have random connection issues after using Tunnelblick or Viscosity, where existing connections don't seem to drop (SSH, Skype, Hangouts,...) but nothing new can be established, ie. ping to 8.8.8.8 times out. It is pretty obvious because IRC warns about reconnections.

Using a MacBook Pro Retina 13" Early 2015 with Yosemite 10.10.3

- connection issues last between a few seconds and up to 15 minutes, I monitored this with a continuous ping to 8.8.8.8 and other destinations, and they time out, eventually working again by itself
- connected by wifi, but connection to router is not affected, ping to 192.168.1.1 works fine even when external ping is timing out
- other computers/phones in the same network don't have this issue, including a 2011 MacBook Pro with same 10.10.3 that IIRC used TunnelBlick recently
- wifi disconnect/reconnect fixes the connection, and so it does [refreshing the DHCP lease](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/11/renew-dhcp-lease-mac-os-x/) with 
  `echo "add State:/Network/Interface/en0/RefreshConfiguration temporary" | sudo scutil`
- after restarting everything works fine until Tunnelblick/Viscosity are used. Then the issue starts to happen randomly again, even after closing them
- Completely uninstalling Tunnelblick also made the issue go away, but need the VPN at some point

It would help to at least be able to unload Tunnelblick/Viscosity completely without the need to restart

Comment: I confirm the same issue on almost the same machine. Untill I restart, some resources I used to access while was connected to VPN can no longer be access and ae giving ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID in Chrome, for example (I am talking about HTTP resource at the moment)

Comment: In my case I can workaround by refreshing DHCP with this script

`echo "add State:/Network/Interface/en0/RefreshConfiguration temporary" | scutil`

Seems I'm losing the config every 15 minutes or so, with another script I monitor that and refresh DHCP automatically. No idea what's the cause yet

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to "uninstall", "unload", or "quit" Tunnelblick to make your issue go away.

In some situations, where the OpenVPN configuration itself is faulty (and it sounds like yours is), you might need to have Tunnelblick "Reset the primary interface after disconnecting". You can do that by selecting the configuration(s) you wish to modify in Tunnelblick's "VPN Details…" window, then clicking the "Advanced" button and putting a check in the corresponding checkbox.

For further Tunnelblick support, you should use the Tunnelblick Discussion Group at

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/tunnelblick-discuss

Before you post to that group, please read

https://code.google.com/p/tunnelblick/wiki/cBeforeYouPost

Comment: Tried the "Reset the primary interface after disconnecting" option but issue is still happening, both while connected to VPN and after disconnecting.

Mailed the group too https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tunnelblick-discuss/xz6Z5to8pKM

Answer (score 1):

On mac en0 and en1 refer to your physical/wireless interface.

The problem is flushing the lease from the openvpn server on the client.

These leases can be flushed on a mac client so that tunnelblick can reassign the client vpn ip addrees.

1. Turn off wireless interface manually or type:

   sudo ifconfig en0 down
2. Flush the routes

   sudo route flush
3. Turn the wireless interface back on or type

   sudo ifconfig en0 up